# Why is my sqlalchemy/sqlite update so slow?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy on a sqlite database. If I execute a bunch of select statements, it is more than 10x faster than executing a bunch of updates on the very same entries.

Doing this 1000 times takes 5.12 seconds:

```
update_stmnt = sqlalchemy.update(table).where(table.c.id==my_id).values(para_type=my_label, score=my_score)
conn.execute(update_stmnt)
```

Whereas doing this 1000 times takes only takes 428ms:

```
select_st = sqlalchemy.select([table]).where(table.c.id == my_id)
res = conn.execute(select_st)
```

Why might the select statement be so much faster than the update? Is there any way I can structure my update statement to make it faster?

Comment: I'd also note that the things I'm storing in the update are very small, just a single float and a string of max 7 chars.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the fields?

Comment: The id field is indexed. para_type and score are not indexed. Do I need to index those to make the update go fast? I thought it would grab the whole row when it does the "where" clause, but perhaps I'm mistaken? Thanks